# Unity Rendering Pipeline 2D Lights is not working in Some Devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, pipeline

I am working in unity 2019.4.21.. I am working on 2d runner game. While trying to add URP 2d lighting in my project. While run my project ..some devices are not working properly .

It says

UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.UniversalRenderPipeline.RenderSingleCamera (UnityEngine.Rendering.ScriptableRenderContext context, UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.CameraData cameraData, System.Boolean anyPostProcessingEnabled) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal.Light2DLookupTexture.CreateFalloffLookupTexture () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal.Render2DLightingPass.Execute (UnityEngine.Rendering.ScriptableRenderContext context, UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.RenderingData& renderingData) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

Texture creation failed. 'R8G8B8A8_SRGB' is not supported for Sample usage on this platform. Use 'SystemInfo.IsFormatSupported' C# API to check format support.

UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.UniversalRenderPipeline.RenderSingleCamera (UnityEngine.Rendering.ScriptableRenderContext context, UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.CameraData cameraData, System.Boolean anyPostProcessingEnabled) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

at

UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.ScriptableRenderer.ExecuteRenderPass (UnityEngine.Rendering.ScriptableRenderContext context, UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.ScriptableRenderPass renderPass, UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.RenderingData& renderingData, System.Int32 eyeIndex) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.ScriptableRenderer.ExecuteRenderPass (UnityEngine.Rendering.ScriptableRenderContext context, UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.ScriptableRenderPass renderPass, UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.RenderingData& renderingData, System.Int32 eyeIndex) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

How to make my 2d game game work in all devices.. In ipad ios 10.3 also not working...

So whats wrong in my settings. Is it problem in Camera,Texture ,Lighting ...

What i have to do for solve this problem...